# Current into level shifter IC from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet, level-shifting

I am trying to do a power assessment of a microcontroller (TMS320F28379D, datasheet link: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sprs880o/sprs880o.pdf?ts=1702312460730)

From the below datasheet, is \$ 4mA \$ the maximum current that the pins of the microcontroller configured as output can supply?

[image: Microcontroller]

Now, the output pins of the microcontroller is connected to a level-shifter IC's \$ 3.3V \$ side, for shifting to \$ 5V \$ (SN74LVC4245A, datasheet link: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc4245a.pdf?ts=1702310500407).

In the table below, I am unable to find the current that the input pins of the level shifter IC will take.

[image: Level shifter IC]

My understanding is that even though the microcontroller's input pins can supply a current of \$ 4 mA \$, the actual current will depend on the output stage, which in this case is the level shifter IC.

Am I looking at the wrong data, or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Depends on your circuit. What are you loading with what? Please draw a (simplified) schematic.

Comment: Pay attention to note (3).

Comment: @winny The microcontroller's output pins are connected to the 3.3V side of the level shifter IC. I will try to update the question with a schematic.

Comment: @Hearth So, does this mean that whatever output pin from the microcontroller connected to the 3.3V side of the level shifter IC will add an additional 0.5mA to the supply current? I apologize if my understanding is wrong as I am new to reading datasheets and understanding these ICs.

Comment: @curious_direwolf Sorry, I meant note (2). That's close to but not exactly what note (3) means, but that's not the note I meant to call your attention to anyway.

Comment: The input current into the level shifter is so small you can treat it as zero for DC purposes. For switching it's basically an open circuit with the specified pF capacitance across it.

Answer (score 3):

The input pins take a maximum of either +/-5uA (control inputs) or +/-50uA (I/O pins). Typical is probably in the nA or less at room temperature.

Of course the pins also have a small amount of capacitance (as will the traces used to connect the two) so there is a brief pulse of current whenever the levels change.

Supply current is another matter.

From the schematic, you are using it in the recommended configuration with CMOS input levels so:

Icca should be < 80uA

Iccb should be < 50uA

None of which is supplied by the MCU pins, of course.

Comment: How to go about computing the supply current from the datasheets for this arrangement?

Comment: That's another question and I would like to see the simplified schematic including all supplies.

Comment: I have added the schematic.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: So the supply current for B port is <50 uA, and the input pins (3.3 V side) of the level-shifter will only take 5uA, and the microcontroller outputs also will supply the same 5uA, is that correct?

Comment: So the I_ccb specification is for all the input pins?

Comment: Oh sorry, is the 50 uA you mentioned the sum of all the currents from the 10 output pins, with each pin being 5 uA? I can't find any specification with 50uA other than I_ccb.

Comment: Sorry  I mis remembered, you are correct 5uA vs. 1uA. Gawk. have to go, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> *My understanding is that even though the microcontroller's input pins
> can supply a current of 4mA, the actual current will depend on the
> output stage, which in this case is the level shifter IC. Am I looking
> at the wrong data, or is my understanding wrong?*

The level shifter provides buffered outputs so, the input current into port A/B of the level shifter is not dependent on the output current from port B/A.

Input pins take up to +/- 5 μA.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with a schematic. How can the supply current from the 3.3 V supply of the level shifter IC be computed?

Comment: I'm sorry but, I answered your original question and this new added question is beyond what was originally asked. Try asking a brand new question instead and remove the additional question you have just added. This is a question and answer site and, your original question is now answered. Please don't turn your question into a chameleon.

Comment: I apologize. I will post a new question.